# strip whitespaces before and after a variabhle array from form with multiple entries

Tags: php

I have a form that inputs data  using explode and splits the  entry into 2 fields so from

```
START POINTS
_3Bug_Salad 1
devinm21 1
Misfit_Eye1 3
Mrslookingfor25 3
Kaibrosky 5
sajoma 6
BRs_Ronycezar 14
UBG_Arielle 19
SG_Bluemango22 29
DJ_Habs 10
STOP POINTS
```

it puts into  PlayerName and points which works almost perfect the only issue is when I have a space  before or 2 spaces after the names  it stops the code

here is the code I am using

```
    $Points = explode("\n", $Points);
    foreach ($Points as $v)
    {
    if ($v == "") continue;
    $v = explode (" ", $v);
    if (count($v) != 2)
    die("Incorrect values in POINTS input (check spaces!)<br>");
    if (strstr(strtolower($v[1]), 'points')) continue;
    $r = mysql_query("insert into points values ('','${v[0]}', 
    ${v[1]}, '".$_POST["tourdate"]."', '".$_POST["tourtime"]."')");
    if (!$r) die (mysql_error());
    }
    echo "Points submitted Successfully";
```

How would I set it to trim the names so that it can only start with a alphanumeric or _ and only have one space after the name and if not remove the whitespaces

to explain better

```
_3Bug_Salad 1 works
 _3Bug_Salad 1 doesnt work
_3Bug_Salad   1 doesnt work
```

where I need all 3 to submit 
      _3Bug_Salad to player name and
1 to points column

Comment: reviewing code and was wondering if there was a way of using  preg_replace: 
     
$Points = explode("\n", $Points); in the "\n" space

Answer (score 0):

```
$v = array_filter( explode (" ", trim($v)) , "strlen");
```

Try this.

Comment: Now  the  one that was working isn't working either saying check spaces

Comment: the issue is the start points and stop points   also strip which echoes back the spacing error this is a standard format used
START POINTS <=---triggers the insert function  <-doesnt get  inserted     
_3Bug_Salad 1     
devinm21 1    
Misfit_Eye1 3    
Mrslookingfor25 3    
Kaibrosky 5    
sajoma 6    
BRs_Ronycezar 14     
UBG_Arielle 19    
SG_Bluemango22 29    
DJ_Habs 10     
STOP POINTS<-- DOesnt get put in db

Comment: I can't understand what you mean.